# Duplicate rows showing up as a result of Muenchian grouping in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I have an XSLT transformation that's returning a lot of duplicate items, as seen here:
[image: Example report] after the snip, the second category shows up at the bottom:
[image]

This is what it's supposed to look like:
[image: Proper report example]

The way this report is structured is:

```
Project
  > Phases (formatted with light grey background)
    > Categories (if any, formatted with light blue background)
      > Deliverables (formatted with white background)
        > Sub-deliverables
```

The hierarchy works, but there's just too much.  I'm not really sure what's going on at this stage.  I'm using the Muenchian Method in XSLT 1.0.

- Here is my input: http://pastebin.com/uJw1sPEQ
- Here is my transformation: http://pastebin.com/7cJd6bj5

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that looks strange is this line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Project-Phases', concat(ProjectNo, '|', Phase))[1][ProjectNo=current()/ProjectNo])]" mode="phase"/>
```

The `[ProjectNo=current()/ProjectNo]` part should not be attached to the key. It should instead be moved after the last `]`.